# how is document.form.submit() received in code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, submit, session-state

I have `document.form1.submit()` in javascript. I want to know how it's received in code behind. In which class, in which method? Something like that. Coz I want to get the value inside a textbox to store it in session. And do i need an actual "submit" button for this to work? This really confuses me.

If i put it like this:

```
function CallSubmit() {
                var thetext = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
                document.form1.submit(thetext);
            }
```

will I be able to pass the value of textbox1 to a specific method in code behind if it has, like, a receiving variable? I mean, how do i get the value of textbox1?

By the way, I'm trying to do this before the page unloads. Because I need to store the text from textbox1 so that I can re-assign that value back after the page refreshes.

Comment: Are you using web forms?

Comment: If the textbox is in the form then it will be submitted, you do not need to pass the value into the submit() function. Some example code would help though if it's not working

Comment: @AdamHeath can you tell me first how to get the value of textbox1 and where to put that particular code? If I still can't make it work after that, then I'll go post some more codes.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I use this function in the window.onbeforeunload event in javascript so that i could get the value of textbox1 before the meta refresh. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the post back values on code behind using the 'Form' as

```
Request.Form["textbox1"]
```

and if you read this `Request.Form` you get all data from post

**Comments**.
In asp.net we general avoid to use direct the `Request.Form` and we use asp.net controls that all ready handle the post values.

For example if you use an `asp:TextBox` with `ID=textBox1` then you read the post from   `textBox1.Text`
and if you like to read it using the `Request.Form` you need to call the `Request.Form[textBox1.UniqueID]`

The `textBox1.UniqueID` is the `name` value on the html control, and the name used for the post back.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but I'm afraid there's still something wrong here somewhere. Will the window.onbeforeunload work well for what I'm trying to do, getting the value of textbox1 before the page refreshes? I'm using meta refresh. Please help me.

Comment: @Artemis I think that you have mix up the thinks - the `.sumbit(somevalue)` is not existing, the way that you post something is not that. You make a form, you .submit() the form, and all the parametres inside that form are submitted. Please start from the basic lessons to see how this work.

Comment: Yea I changed that part already when @Adam said I don't need to pass the value into the submit function. It's now just `document.form1.submit();`. But in which sub routine do i put the `Request.Form("textbox1")` so that i can get the value when the form submits. I'm sorry, I know answering my questions is such a bother. So I appreciate that you're taking the time to help me.